# Checking for similarity of text in two text strings

Tags: r

I have two strings of text (typically two paragraphs). I am looking to check for the "similarity" between them, e.g. check if one paragraph is a plagiarised version of the other. Ideally I need a similarity score, as well as an indication of where the similarities are. I prefer to do this fully in R. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of stings can be measured with the levenshtein distance (or concepts that build on top of that). The main idea is to quantify the "editiing distance" of strings: how many letters need to be included/excluded/changed, etc (depending on the algorithm more or less types of editing are allowed). A package in R for this task would be fuzzyjoin.

To look up the similarities you could cut both texts (original and suposed plagiate) in sentences and build the fuzzy joins on this - Then you can filter for best matches. The topic is a bit tricky so I recomend trying out different algorithms (jaccard distance, damerau levenshtein, etc). A start into the topic can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/readme/README.html